# Undefined method logged_in? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I can't make head or tail of this (but I'm probably being an idiot).  I have a class `ApplicationController` that contains the following method:

```
def logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end

if logged_in?
  load_and_authorize_resource :unless => :devise_controller?, :except => :show
end
```

This gives me an error:

> undefined method `logged_in?' for ApplicationController:Class

This method is clearly defined, how is it coming back as undefined?

Comment: If you call it at the top level (which you do immediately after defining it) you're calling it at the class level, not at the instance level. You've defined an instance method; it's not available outside of an instance.

Comment: so, you have the ApplicationController class, and in it you have those 6 lines of code ?, right how you posted them ?, I mean, the 'if logged_in?' line comes after the 'end' of the 'def logged_in?' method?. If so, you're doing it wrong. The 'if logged_in?' code needs to be used inside your methods, not outside. You use code outside methods to do perhaps some kind of metaprogramming to define other methods, etc.

Comment: @123 Have you still got this issue? I have had a similar issue that I solved today

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best place to declare it is in `/helpers/application_helper.rb` instead of application_controller.

Also, to verify if a user is signed in, Devise provides the following helper `user_signed_in?`.

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to write:

```
helper_method :logged_in?
```

in `ApplicationController`.